# Is there a faster way to get the Q matrix from a QR decomposition in R?

Tags: r, matlab, matrix

In R programming, the QR decomposition function returns an object of class 'qr' that returns matrix of the same size as the original matrix, but does not explicitly contain the Q and R matrices. To reconstruct the Q matrix, you must first run the qr function and then qr.Q as so.

```
qr_object <- qr(A)
Q <- qr.Q(qr_object)
R <- qr.R(qr_object)
```

Reconstructing the Q matrix takes considerable runtime. But in MATLAB you can just call

```
[Q,R] = qr(A)
```

and it will explicitly return both parts of the factorization. I don't have MATLAB, so can't test if `qr` ends up being slower if you specify `[Q,R]=qr(A)` as opposed to `R = qr(A)` but is R's ability to return the Q matrix slower than MATLAB's? And if so, is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: R uses LAPACK backend for qr decomposition, which is pretty optimized.  Not sure what MATLAB uses (probably also LAPACK), but I'd be surprised if it is much more performant.  I don't have MATLAB either so can't run a speed comparison, but that would probably be the first thing to try

Comment: BTW in python, like matlab, you can also use `q, r = np.linalg.qr(X)`.  You could do a speed comparison between R and python (numpy also uses LAPACK) to see whether there is any benefit to generating the Q,R matrices in a single line of code rather than two.

Comment: Something relevant: [Fast QR factorization in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72723667/4891738).